# EditText to ListView Through SD Card reading

Tags: android, listview, android-edittext

So I need help, I don't know what's I get no errors nothing. Just isn't working
So I got a EditText (TextInput) You write something there for example "potato", when you press the Button (save and addButton) should take whats in the TextInput and put it into the SD card and then the ListView (TextOutput) Should read from that folder and display what it says. Hope you guys understand

The Code I'm using (Updated)

```
public File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/accelerometer.html");

public void onCreate1(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.textOutput);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> arrAdap = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    lv.setAdapter(arrAdap);

    findViewById(R.id.save).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            save();
            try {
                arrAdap.addAll(load());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            arrAdap.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

}

public void save() {
    String textInput = mTextInput.getText().toString().trim();
    if(textInput.equals("")) {
        return;
    }
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public ArrayList<String> load() throws IOException{
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    ObjectInputStream ois = null;
    ArrayList<String> returnlist = null;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        returnlist = (ArrayList<String>) ois.readObject();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if(fis != null)
            fis.close();
        if(ois != null)
            ois.close();
    }

    return returnlist;
    }

@Override
public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

Thanks for all the help in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

add `bufferWritter.flush();` after `bufferWritter.write(TextImput);`

EDIT:
try this code:

```
private File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/accelerometer.html");

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    ListView lv = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.textOutput);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> arrAdap = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
    lv.setAdapter(arrAdap);

    findViewById(R.id.save).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            save();
            arrAdap.add(load());
            arrAdap.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });

}

public void save() {
    String textInput = mTextInput.getText().toString().trim();
    if(textInput.equals("")
        return;

    AddButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {    //i don't know what this should do
        @Override                                           //you set the same text to the same textview 
        public void onClick(View arg0) {                    //-> does nothing
            mTextInput.setText(mTextInput.getText());

        }
    });

    ArrayList<String> input = new ArrayList<>();
    input.add(textInput);

    FileOutputStream fos;
    ObjectOutputStream oos;

    try {
        fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
        oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        oos.writeObject(input);
        oos.flush();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if(fos != null)
            fos.close();
        if(oos != null)
            oos.close();
    }
}

public ArrayAdapter<String> load(){
    FileInputStream fis;
    ObjectInputStream ois;
    ArrayList<String> returnlist;
    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        returnlist = (ArrayList<String>) ois.readObject();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if(fis != null)
            fis.close();
        if(ois != null)
            ois.close();
    }

    return returnlist;
}
```

it just coded out of my mind. nothing is tested.

maybe you have to handle some IOExceptions in the finally statement but just put another try{...}catch(){...} around it.

I have also added a comment.

Comment: Didn't solve it, maybe are part of the problem but didn't fix it completely, could you look if you find something else too?

Comment: i did some changes in my post. dotn forget to get the permission for external writing/reading <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: it should work if you rename onCreate1 to `protected void onCreate` and add @Override above it.  Just give it a try

Comment: Done it, Get an error only option is Rename. How to fix?
`@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { `

Error description:
Link all references for a local rename (does not change references 
in other files)

Comment: you have to delete the old onCreate method.  If you want you can post the whole class here or at [this page](http://textuploader.com/) for example. Select the java syntax highlighting.

Comment: Nop, Now the app don't even start "Unfortunatly, app has Stopped."

Comment: I cannot help you without the whole code. Just upload it.